# Did apple allow Third Party Payment integration throughout the world

Tags: ios, flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, applepay

I have developed an app, for India and the United Kingdom, but it's getting rejected in App Store, due to non-compliance with payment rules. After reading the autogenerated message by apple, I concluded that maybe I am using stripe as my payment option, and not Apple Pay.
reading the latest news, today, I read apple allows third party payments in South Korea. Does that mean this option is not allowed throughout the world?

Comment: Third party payment is not allowed in all countries. It's selectively implemented.

Comment: so is it necessary to use IAP for digital goods well in the countries I have mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for digital content subscription ,you need to have in app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't use 3rd-party payment methods for in-app purchases in iOS apps.